# The minimal polynomial of a matrix

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-analysis

Let $A=(a_{kl})$ be the  matrix in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ given by
$a_{kk}=0$ and $a_{kl}=\frac12$ if $k\neq l$.  Let $D$ be the diagonal matrix in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$  with $D=\operatorname{diag}(n,\frac{2n+1}{4},,\cdots,\frac{2n+1}{4})$.

Q. Any suggestion to find the minimal polynomial/eigenvalues of $A+D$ ?

Comment: This sounds a bit like homework to me. However, a hint might be that $A+D$ is always symmetric and hence diagonalizable. Thus the minimal polynomial is always $\prod (X-\lambda_i)$, where $\lambda_i$ are the distinct eigenvalues of $A+B$. I would then use a computer algebra system to have a look at the eigenvalues for small values of $n$. Maybe there is a pattern.

Comment: Seems like a good use case for the matrix determinant lemma. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vectors with first entry 0 and total sum 0 are eigenvectors with eigenvalue $2n-1/4$.

As the matrix is symmetric the orthogonal of the above is stable under the operator. This orthogonal consists of the vectors having last n-1 coordinates equal.

This is a 2-dimensional matrix which you can easily diagonalize. In total you get what Neil Strickland suggested in the comments by experiments (by the way I agree this is a bit easy for MO).

Comment: Thanks, Nice argument.